# Updating object's LocalDate attribute with query. Parameter value did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Vaadin + Spring + MySQL

I try to update my object's LocalDate attribute via query with java.time.LocalDate attribute converted to java.sql.Date

Entity:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTERPRISES")
public class Enterprise {

    int enterpriseId;
    String name;
    LocalDate expiryDate;

    public Enterprise(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Enterprise() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    public int getEnterpriseId() {
        return enterpriseId;
    }
    @Column
    public String getName() { return name; }

    @Column
    public LocalDate getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    public void setEnterpriseId(int enterpriseId) {
        this.enterpriseId = enterpriseId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public void setExpiryDate(LocalDate expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }
}
```

Service layer:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Service
public class EnterpriseService {

    private static EnterpriseService enterpriseService;
    private EnterpriseDao enterpriseDao;

    public EnterpriseService(EnterpriseDao enterpriseDao) {
        this.enterpriseDao = enterpriseDao;
    }

    public void updateExpiryDate(int enterpriseId, LocalDate newExpiryDate) {
        Date expiryDate = Date.valueOf(newExpiryDate);
        enterpriseDao.updateExpiryDate(enterpriseId, expiryDate);
    }

}
```

repository layer:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public interface EnterpriseDao extends CrudRepository<Enterprise, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update Enterprise e set e.expiryDate = :expiryDate where e.enterpriseId = :enterpriseId")
    void updateExpiryDate(@Param(value = "enterpriseId") int enterpriseId, @Param(value = "expiryDate") Date expiryDate);

}
```

When I try to call method in my application:

```
enterpriseService.updateExpiryDate(enterpriseX.getEnterpriseId(), LocalDate.of(2022, 12, 12));
```

I get exception:

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2022-12-12] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2022-12-12] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]

I tried changing date types in DAO method to LocalDate but with no success

Comment: Since the parameter expiryDate of updateExpiryDate() is a java.sql.Date, I don't understand how you can call it with a LocalDate.of() without a compiler error. You must have changed something before you copied your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the attribute `expiryDate` on your `Enterprise` entity is a `java.time.LocalDate`, the parameter `:expiryDate` in the query must be a `java.time.LocalDate`. Therefore, you should change the parameter `expiryDate` of `updateExpiryDate()`.

Comment: Thank you!  That was it. I tried it before and didn't really paid attencion to logs so I immediatly jumped to conclusio that it has something to do with Date type. Now when I tried it, and TransactionRequiredException error occured, I readed more about it. @Transactional annotation was missing in my query.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. If you can, please click on the up arrow to validate this answer.

Comment: I can't yet, since I'm new and have too little reputation